# Issues unlisting a nested-list

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, named

I have list x and y; x unlists and gives me what I want...
However, y does not I think it is because its a list from the biostrings package creating problems for me. I cannot include everything as this is biological data but I have tried to include some code and data to understand my problem.

**Example of x ~ normal nested list**

```
x1 = list(c(218,215, 212, 207, 189, 178, 163, 160, 154, 146, 140, 136, 112, 110,  89,  70,  68,  66,  62,  56,  52,  47,  34,  27,   9))
x2 = list(c(3, 1))
x<- list(c(x1,x2)
lapply(rapply(x, enquote, how="unlist"), eval)


[[1]]
 [1] 218 215 212 207 189 178 163 160 154 146 140 136 112 110  89  70  68  66  62  56  52  47  34
[24]  27   9

[[2]]
[1] 3 1
```

unlisting works perfectly for x~

```
unlist(x)
 [1] 218 215 212 207 189 178 163 160 154 146 140 136 112 110  89  70  68  66  62  56  52  47  34
[24]  27   9   3   1
```

I cannot provide all of the code to show an example of y, as its biological data and 300 lines of code. Basically, it is based on cross-referencing a GRAnge objects. I am finding overlaps with my data and a reference genome.

**List Y**

```
y = CPGi_Pos2[1:2]
> y
$`1`
[1] 172 167 163 157 153 151 149  79  73

$`2`
 [1] 418 404 403 392 391 389 388 371 370 352 351 349 348 339 338 332

class(y)
[1] "list"

unlist(y)
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29 210 211 212 213 214 215 
172 167 163 157 153 151 149  79  73 418 404 403 392 391 389 388 371 370 352 351 349 348 339 338 
216 
332 

str(x)
List of 13833
 $ 1    : int [1:9] 172 167 163 157 153 151 149 79 73
 $ 2    : int [1:16] 418 404 403 392 391 389 388 371 370 352 ...
```

I need to remove the names attached to list y as seen below. I want to unlist y and have it look like x

```
> str(x)
 int [1:1009322] 218 215 212 207 189 178 163 160 154 146 ...
> str(y)
 Named int [1:745078] 172 167 163 157 153 151 149 79 73 418 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:745078] "11" "12" "13" "14" ...
```

Comment: ask questions about Bioconductor on the Bioconductor support site https://support.bioconductor.org

Comment: *"unsure why it has 11-27 first"* Well, it does not! Those are `names`, an attribute of the object. `str(y)` is clear when it outputs `Named int` and then `- attr(*, "names")` followed by the values. Try `y[1]` and `y["11"]`. Not my downvote but I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Firstly, apologies for the mistake but considering I am only 6 months into learning R and Matlab its ok to be wrong. That is the whole point of asking on a forum.

Comment: does `unname(unlist(y))` do what you want?

Comment: aye cheers, lol post as an answer and I will tick it